# Execution failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I picked up someone else's project and when I asked AS to run the project on my AVD, it pops me an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'ca.gggolf.aminutegolf'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

I don't know what to do.. Everything else works fine and the app was working a couple of years ago when it was first made.

Comment: was the project originally written for Eclipse? You say it's a couple years old, which is why I ask.

Comment: add please your `build.gradle` and tell me whch version od Android Studio you're  using

Comment: Done! So do you have any idea...?

Comment: what java version are you using?

Comment: 1.8 but the older version is on 1.7 or maybe even 1.6

Comment: ok, so `File -> Project Settings` find Java SDK, if you find that is actually used jdk1.8 change it to jdk1.7. then `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: I did as you said but still have my errors.. it comes from :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug. Both errors seems to come from this one..

Comment: Run the command `gradle clean build --stacktrace` and show us the stacktrace. Also scroll up and see if qthere is more details of the crash above the last lines

Comment: You did it, good. Now, close Android Studio, then  go to your app directory and delete folder  called `build`,  then go to folder `app` in your app directory and delete folder with the same name (with name `build`). Now open your Android Studiom select `Build -> Clean` and then `Build -> Rebuild project`. It should work

Answer (score 2):

Enable multidex for your project. Add below line to gradle defaultConfig:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Also add multidex dependency to gradle's dependencies :

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If an error is related to dex than it will tell you. Author didn't mention it. So your answer doesn't make any snse

Answer (score 1):

Check your location address of exist project. if you use special character like :

```
( / | \ + = * ... )
```

In folder and sub-folders name, you should change it and check it out.

I changed my folder name from `"UI/UX"` to `"UiUx"` and its done :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm back at this question simply because it got many views.

First, thanks all for the help. I managed to run the app by creating a new project on Android Studio and importing classes one at a time while making sure the code was still fine. Maybe creating a new project added some parameters that were not present in the older version of the project.

If someone has a better explanation, feel free to answer!

Comment: creating a new project and copying classes one by one is impossible for some projects which have a lots of files into it..

Comment: I know, I don't say it's the best solution, I just said it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check your lib versions. In my case it was old Realm plugin that was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error happens to me. I don't have any java compiler errors.

And seems this issue related to the build cache of a project.

So it can be solved like this

1. Build/Clean Project
2. Build/Make Project or Build APK

Answer (score 0):

Build with below command, this command will point the exact point in source code where the compilation error is getting generated.

```sh
gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```